# How to test in app purchase with google play, whilst using a debug app/package name

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, play-billing-library

For my debug build of my app, I append `.debug` to the package name so that I can test two diff apps etc.

However, when I come to try and test purchasing in app stuff, using `BillingClient`, it doesn't work because it's looking for those in app purchase ids using the debug package name.

Is there any way around me testing everything with my release build? It's quite time consuming to swap back and forth and test with a build that has proguard on and takes ages to compile.

Is there a way of changing the packagename used? (From what I can see it just takes a `Context`). Or is there a way to create a fake account in the play store to create these in app ids against?